Show that $ Y $ is separable, and that the spectrum of $ A$ consists of eigenvalues only.
Let  $A: X \to Y$ be a linear operator defined on a dense subspace $ X $ of a Banach space $ Y $. Assume that $ A $ has an inverse that is compact as a linear operator on $ Y $. Show that $ Y $ is separable, and that the spectrum of $ A $ consists of eigenvalues only.
What I understand in part one it that I have to prove the countability of the set $X$, but I do not know how!
This is my try for solving part 2:
Since $A^{-1}$ is compact, its spectrum $\sigma(A^{-1})$ consists of $0$ and eigenvalues with finite multiplicity that can accumulate only at $0$.
For $A$, the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ consists of all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $A - \lambda I$ is not invertible. We need to show that every element of $\sigma(A)$ is an eigenvalue.
For $\lambda \neq 0$, if $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$, then $A - \lambda I$ is not invertible. Since $A^{-1}$ is compact, $(A - \lambda I)^{-1}$ is also compact when it exists. This implies that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.
To see why, note that if $A - \lambda I$ were invertible, its inverse would be compact, which contradicts the assumption that $A$ has a compact inverse unless $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.
Consider $0 \in \sigma(A)$. Since $A$ is invertible with $A^{-1}$ compact, $0 \notin \sigma(A)$. If $0$ were in the spectrum, then $A$ would not be invertible, which contradicts the given conditions.
Hence, the spectrum of $A$ consists entirely of eigenvalues. That is,
$$ \sigma(A) = \left \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \mid A - \lambda I \text{ is not invertible} \right \}$$
consists solely of eigenvalues of $A$.

The range of a compact operator is separable, so $X$ is separable. As $X$ is dense in $Y$, so $Y$ is separable as well.

@DavidGao Thanks, so I need just to reproof that the image of a compact operator is separable. Is the solution for the second part correct?

The proof for the second part doesn’t make much sense to me. That $A^{-1}$ is compact does not seem to immediately imply $(A - \lambda I)^{-1}$ is compact whenever it exists. Nor does it imply anything about points in the spectrum, since those correspond to the cases where $(A - \lambda I)^{-1}$ does not exist. (I don’t know how to prove the claim though. I was going to suggest holomorphic functional calculus, but I don’t know how that is supposed to work for unbounded operators.)

If $A-\lambda I$ is injective so is  $A^{-1}(A-\lambda I)=I-\lambda A^{-1}.$ As $A^{-1}$ is compact we get $\lambda^{-1}\notin \sigma(A^{-1}),$ i.e. the product $A^{-1}(A-\lambda I)$ is invertible. Therefore $A-\lambda I$ is invertible as well. Hence the spectrum of $A$ consists of eigenvalues.
By the way the reasoning shows that if $A-\lambda I$ is invertible then $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is compact, since it is a product of $A^{-1}$ and $(I-\lambda A^{-1})^{-1}.$
